# Last row verification in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, verification

I have this body of code that verifies rows in a DataGridView. It checks if the content of a cell in that row is between 0 to 10 and if it is 11+, it would be highlighted Red.

The issue that I have come across is that even if all numbers are within 0-10, the last row in the row would be highlighted Red.
Is this some sort of end of file situation?

In the code, if the cell is null, nothing happens. So I figured the last row should have nothing done to it as well (as long as it is 0-10)

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If Not row.Cells("F3").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        Dim cellNumber As Integer

        If Integer.TryParse(row.Cells("F3").Value, cellNumber) AndAlso cellNumber >= 0 AndAlso cellNumber <= 10 Then
            'All pass verification, Do nothing
        Else
            'Point out the wrong value 
            row.Cells("F3").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Else
        '    MessageBox.Show("Not a number!")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead?

Comment: @the_lotus I have not. my code does what I need it to do in terms of verifying if an integer is not in the range that I specified, but for some reason the last row in the Datagridview falls within the else statement and becomes highlighted Red. (the last row in the datagridview is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the line that I was missing .. 
I had to add:

> AndAlso Not row.Cells("F11").value Is Nothing

to have :

> If Not row.Cells("F3").Value Is DBNull.Value AndAlso Not row.Cells("F11").value is Nothing Then

Answer (score 1):

In your CellValidating event, you should check if the ColumnIndex is the desired column and the current row is not the new row. After that you should check if the value falls within your range.

Take a look at this example (I don't know what index F3 is, so I'm assuming 0):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso Not DataGridView1.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
        Dim value As String = e.FormattedValue.ToString()
        Dim numericValue As Integer

        With DataGridView1.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells.Item(e.ColumnIndex).Style
            If Integer.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString, numericValue) AndAlso numericValue >= 0 AndAlso numericValue <= 10 Then
                .BackColor = Color.White
                .ForeColor = Color.Black
            Else
                .BackColor = Color.Red
                .ForeColor = Color.White
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this suggestion out. 
also, F3 was the column in the datagridview. thank you